# Move a canvas with keycode - JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm very new to javascript. With help from google I wrote this. I don't know why but when I press either key 'A' or 'D' nothing happens. I just can't figure out why, to me it all makes perfect sence. Can you help me?

```
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var X = 50;
var Y = 50;
var WIDTH = 35;
var HEIGHT = 35;
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(X,Y,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
document.addEventListener("keydown", draw);
function draw(e){
    switch(e.which || e.keyCode){
        case 68:
            x += 5;
            break;
        case 65:
            x -= 5;
            break;
  }
  ctx.clear();
  ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
  ctx.fillRect(X,Y,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
}
```

and HTML:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="350px" height="500px"></canvas>
```

Here's a fiddle if that helps. https://jsfiddle.net/Scrubben/gmd537k1/26/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working code. Make sure the JavaScript is case sensitive. So `var X !== x`. 
And use `ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);` instead of `ctx.clear()`

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var x = 50;
var y = 50;
var WIDTH = 35;
var HEIGHT = 35;
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(x, y, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
document.addEventListener("keydown", draw);

function draw(e) {
  switch (e.which || e.keyCode) {
    case 68:
      x += 5;
      break;
    case 65:
      x -= 5;
      break;
  }
  // ctx.clear();
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
}
```

```css
#canvas {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500px" height="500px"></canvas>
```

Comment: Very good, thanks!